# Query to aggregate data from table into another table based on number of entries of an id column

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table like this:

```
order_id    start_date    end_date    amount    corrected_amount
   1        2020-01-01    2020-01-31    100           95
   1        2020-02-01    2020-02-28    200          200
   1        2020-03-01    2020-03-30    100          100
   1        2020-10-01    2020-11-25    200           95
   2        2020-01-01    2020-05-30    500          250   
   3        2020-01-01    2020-12-31    400            5
```

And I am trying to create a query to aggregate this into a smaller table with just one row per order_id and I need to sum this together using a few rules that I am having some problems implementing.

In the case where there just exists one entry like for id 2 and 3 then I want to return just the order_id start_date, end_date and value from the amount column

In the case where there exists multiple entries like for 1 then I want to return the order_id, the minimum start_date, the maximum end_date, and for every end_date that is "lower" than todays date I want to sum up the corrected_amounts and also add this to the amount where end_date is "bigger" than today.

So for the table above the result would look like

```
order_id     start_date    end_date   amount
   1         2020-01-01    2020-11-25   595
   2         2020-01-01    2020-05-30   500
   3         2020-01-01    2020-12-31   400
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `IF`:

```
WITH TestData AS (
  SELECT 1 as order_id, DATE('2020-01-01') as start_date, DATE('2020-01-31') as end_date, 100 as amount, 95 as corrected_amount UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, DATE('2020-02-01'), DATE('2020-02-28'), 200, 200 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, DATE('2020-03-01'), DATE('2020-03-30'), 100, 100 UNION ALL
  SELECT 1, DATE('2020-10-01'), DATE('2020-11-25'), 200, 95 UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, DATE('2020-01-01'), DATE('2020-05-30'), 500, 250 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, DATE('2020-01-01'), DATE('2020-12-31'), 400, 5 
)
SELECT order_id,
  MIN(start_date) AS start_date,
  MAX(end_date) AS end_date,
  IF(COUNT(*) > 1,
     SUM(IF(end_date < CURRENT_DATE(), corrected_amount, amount)),
     SUM(amount)
    ) as amount
FROM TestData
GROUP BY order_id
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't this return the wrong amount for order_id 2 where end_date is smaller than current date, and I want to return amount not corrected_amount since it is just a single entry with it?

Comment: Sorry, fixed with one more `IF`

Comment: After having tested this solution some more it seems like it doesnt quite work.
the returned values for order_id 1 is two rows not 1, but except that the total sum of the two is correct. I would just need to get bothe the order 1 rows in the same one

Comment: I had to change the query to 
SELECT order_id,
  MIN(start_date) AS start_date,
  MAX(end_date) AS end_date,
  IF(COUNT(*) > 1,
     SUM(IF(end_date < CURRENT_DATE(), corrected_amount, amount)),
     amount)
FROM `pomengine.Testdata.test`
GROUP BY order_id, amount

to include a amount in the GROUP BY to get it to run, that might be the reason it creates wrong sum

Comment: ANY just gives me an error: Unexpected keyword ANY
It seems like just changing ANY to SUM solved it, but I have no idea if that will work and why

Comment: You are correct and my bad again. Fixed and tested. Should have tested it from the very beginning :-)))